# IOException Заданного параметра реестра не существует.

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

После последнего обновления SP2 для visual studio 2012 стало выскакивать исключение

```
IOException Заданного параметра реестра не существует.
```

Место в коде где выскакивает:

```
    //Получаем html код страницы
    var http = new System.Net.WebClient();
    http.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

    string html = http.DownloadString(value.ToString().Trim()); //Вот тут исключение
```

В чем может быть проблема? С чем эта пакость связана?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что же в переменную value записываете? Приведите код.

Comment: а что такое value? Uri?

Comment: value - это переменная типа string, используется в цикле foreach. Ссылка содержащаяся в value.ToString().Trim() 100% корректна и не пустая.

Comment: У меня данный код работает исправно без исключений. Проверял для значения 'http://google.ru' Кстате данное исключение не типично для данного кода, то есть проблема скорей всего не в этом коде. Возможно поможет http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141434/httpclient-request-throws-ioexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@wind](/users/4863/wind)](/users/4863/wind) благодарю, помогла ссылка.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; The following value prevents an IOException from being thrown and caught
; by System.Net.HybridWebProxyFinder.InitializeFallbackSettings() (in System.dll)
; when WebRequest.Create is first called.  By default the "LegacyWPADSupport"
; value doesn't exist, and when InitializeFallbackSettings calls GetValueKind,
; an IOException is thrown.  This adds the value with its default of false to
; prevent the exception.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"LegacyWPADSupport"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"LegacyWPADSupport"=dword:00000000
```